# 3 finger swipe for double screen aquaris m10 remove

Tags: ubuntu-touch, m10

How do i remove the double screen ( activated by 3 finger swipe )
I tested it,but now i can't get rid of it. I tried a lot of other gestures, but no luck.
Aquaris m10 Ubuntu tablet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Add window to small right panel:**

- drag window with three fingers to right and drop on narrow panel that appears

**How to make the small window big again (your question?):**

- drag small panel with three fingers to the left
- the above does not work for all window types - e.g. the gmail app, for this you need to align three fingers virtically along the shadow and drag to the left. A bit tricksy as you need to get your fingers in just the right place.

Finally to remove the small right empty panel carefully place two fingers on the shadow and drag right.

Answer (score 1):

Tap with three fingers into the small window again, and pull it to the left,then it should be big again.

To get rid of the small empty window that will remain, simply slide its left edge to the right side of the screen.